# Enviar el uri para reproducir sonido mediante un array

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Buenas estoy practicando con la típica aplicación donde creando un objeto se llena de parámetros a través de un `array` y luego se envían a otra pantalla esos datos , y me gustaría poder enviar la uri (`R.raw`. "el archivo").

Tengo `listaAnimales.add(Animal(R.drawable.perro, "Perro", "El perro guia de ovejas","R.raw.gallo"))`

y lo recibieria de esta forma `val sonido = bundle.getString("sonido")`

pero en la funcion `val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,).start()`
no me detecta la variable sonido

A mi me gustaría poder clickear un botón y que empezara a reproducirse el sonido enviado

Comment: No necesitas enviar la Uri, debes enviar valores tipo int para que puedan ser reconocidos como recursos del sistema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El array debe ser definido como array de elementos tipo entero ya que accedes a recursos del sistema, en este caso por ejemplo `R.raw.gallo` es un audio que se debe encontrar en el folder `/raw`

Veo que usas Kotlin, este es un ejemplo:

```
 val audio = R.raw.gallo;
 val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audio).start()
```

---

Agrego ejemplos más completos:

#### Reproducir audio almacenado en `/raw` a otra actividad para reproducir mediante `MediaPlayer`.

Desde tu `Activity` realizas el `Intent` enviando el valor de tu audio :

```
 val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
 val message = R.raw.gallo;

 intent.putExtra("audio", message)
 startActivity(intent)
```

En la `Activity` destino recibes el valor y reproduces el audio:

```
  val intent = getIntent();
  val audio = intent.getIntExtra("audio",0)

  val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audio).start()
```

#### Reproducir audios almacenado en `/raw` a otra actividad para reproducir mediante `MediaPlayer`.

Realizas un array de enteros conteniendo los ids de los audios y los envias en el `Intent`:

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
val message: IntArray = intArrayOf(R.raw.perro, R.raw.gato, R.raw.gallo, R.raw.crocodile);

intent.putExtra("audios", message)
startActivity(intent)
```

en la `Activity` destino recibes el array de elementos, y mediante el indice puedes indicar que elemento dentro del array reproducir:

```
val intent = getIntent();
val audios:IntArray = intent.getIntArrayExtra("audios")

val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audios[2]).start()
```

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.